# How to install jupyterlab-plotly labextension using pip nodejs in a virtual environment?

Tags: python, node.js, pip, plotly, jupyter-lab

I am trying to install the jupyterlab plotly extension with this command (according to https://plotly.com/python/getting-started/):

**jupyter labextension install jupyterlab-plotly@4.14.3**

I get this error:

```
An error occured.
ValueError: Please install Node.js and npm before continuing installation. You may be able to install Node.js from your package manager, from conda, or directly from the Node.js website (https://nodejs.org).
See the log file for details:  /tmp/jupyterlab-debug-epx8b4n6.log
```

I didn't install Node.js on system level, but in a virtual environment using pip. Pip list shows both nodejs 0.1.1 and npm 0.1.1 . I am also using ipywidgets in jupyterlab, which requires nodejs and it is working fine.

So I have two questions:

1. How to use plotlywidgets with pip nodejs in a virtual environment?
2. What's the difference between pip nodejs and system level Node.js

Answer (score 4):

No, you have **not** installed node.js. You installed some kind of Python bindings for node ([python-nodejs](https://pypi.org/project/nodejs/), with its [repository](https://github.com/markfinger/python-nodejs) archived by the author) which itself require an actual nodejs. It is dangerous to install stuff from PyPI without checking what you are installing. It could have been a malicious code - you shouldn't just type a name after `pip install` and hope that it installs what you think. It's the same for your `npm` installation (package comes from the same author); both were not updated in the last 6 years and may contain some vulnerabilities so I would uninstall those quickly ;)

It can be seen immediately from the version number that something is wrong because the current nodejs versions are generally >10, (with exact version depending on your JupyterLab version, i.e. either 10 or 12; 14 might work too).

Answer (score 1):

First install nodejs latest version
`conda install nodejs -c conda-forge --repodata-fn=repodata.json`

Then install jupyterlab extension:
`jupyter labextension install jupyterlab-plotly@4.14.3`

Then **RESTART JUPYTER LAB**